# How can I make a change to changes in a git branch?

Tags: git

I have a git branch that I've made some code changes on. However, I've decided that I need to change the command I've added (`static_cast`) to a newer command (`narrow_cast`).

I made a lot of these changes so what I want to do is write a script that:

1. Identifies all the changes between the branch and trunk.
2. Replace the use of `static_cast` to `narrow_cast` in these changes.
3. Writes the result back to the branch.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Do you have a lot of commits into this branch?

Comment: No, only one or two. But the number of lines changed is high and I don't want to repeat all that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try :

- git diff "tag from which you branched"

this will list all your changes , this is also kind of a patch that you can apply again to your code

- git diff "tag from which you branched" > redo_all.patch

in redo_all.patch change the static_cast to narrow_cast (edit replace all .. be careful with replace all)

then create a new branch at same start point

- git apply redo_all.patch

at this point you have a new branch with the correct modifications

advantage of this : you have your old modif on a branch and the new ons on another branch... then when you checked everything is ok you can work to change the branches names

Comment: To summarize, if `topic` is the original branch and HEAD is on the branch you want to change to, you can create the squashed commit with `git diff -u master..topic | sed '/^+ /s/static_cast/narrow_cast/g' | git apply`. This is a sledge-hammer, and you will certainly want to manually inspect the diff.